# "Register in Chrome Web Store" not showing in Google script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, chrome-web-store, google-apps-script-editor

I am trying to publish a script (called "Paypal store" in the scripts gallery) as a web app in Chrome Web Store, but the item "Register in Chrome Web Store" is not showing in the "Publish" menu of the Google script editor (the only items present in this menu are "Publish to gallery" and "Deploy as web app"). What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Register in Chrome Web Store" option only shows up for standalone scripts, not scripts contained in spreadsheets. Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/scripts_containers) for more.